# Gitorious: git-poller won't start

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gitorious

I just installed a fresh gitorious on my server and wanted to test it when I found out that the git-poller didn't run. And it also didn't want to start.

I followed this guide: http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/DebianSqueezeInstallation, my system is Debian Squeeze and Ruby -v says ruby 1.8.7

Everything from that guide works so far. The system is up and running but I can't start the poller. All the poller writes into the logs is the following:

tmp/pids/poller.log

```
*** below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally ***
#<MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- user_auto_completions_helper>
*** below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***
#<NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory>
#<SystemStackError: stack level too deep>
#<fatal: exception reentered>
#<LoadError: no such file to load -- daemons>
#<TypeError: Expected a filter, an endpoint, a callable or a list of any of these.>
#<NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveMessaging>
#<MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- user_auto_completions_helper>
```

tmp/pids/poller.output

```
/home/clients/client1/web85/web/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActiveMessaging (NameError)
        from /home/clients/client1/web85/web/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
        from /home/clients/client1/web85/web/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
        from /home/clients/client1/web85/web/lib/gitorious/messaging/stomp_poller.rb:13
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `start_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/application.rb:292:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:143:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:112:in `catch_exceptions'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.0/lib/daemons.rb:142:in `run'
    from script/poller:30
```

I'm using ispconfig as a webserver management tool, that's where the weird paths are from. I changed all paths from the howto to fit, tho.

Anybody got an idea? I can provide more material if needed, but I just don't know what could be usefull. This is my first question on stackoverflow so please don't shoot me if I didn't do everything right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of reading and trial and error (I started about 3 times from scratch, trying Ruby 1.9.2 and REE both from source and with RVM) I tried another howto[1] which had one big difference to the first one: It suggested downloading and installing Rubygems 1.4.2 instead of the apt-version of Rubygems.

At first I didn't want to do that because I was afraid that it would break my system (there are a lot of other things running on that server, including Redmine) which it did, but after I re-installed all missing gems everything worked again.

Now everything (Gitorious and Redmine) is working with apt-version of Ruby 1.8.7 and the non-apt-version of Rubygems 1.4.2.

[1] http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server/

Since I stumbled upon another, hopefully last problem:
I installed gitorious for my standard web user (in order to respect ISPConfig's policy) and made a new git-user for the repositories. To be able to exchange data I added both to the same usergroup and fixed the permissions.

The problem I ran into was that the git poller added new repositories for his own, that means "git:git" instead of "git:sharedgroup". To fix this you just have to set the default group id for the git-folder (/var/git in my case):

```
chgrp -R <group_name> /var/git
chmod -R g+s /var/git
```

It appears that the two commands above did work but adding a new project broke everything again because the git-poller added a folder for the project and the repository which resulted in the repository-folder having the wrong owner again.

I (hopefully) fixed that with changing my /etc/init.d/git-poller script from

```
/bin/su - git -c "cd /var/www/git.mydomain.com/web;RAILS_ENV=production script/poller $@"
```

to

```
/bin/su - git -c "newgrp <group_name> && cd /var/www/git.mydomain.com/web;RAILS_ENV=production script/poller $@"
```